# How do I sell my equipment for a better price?

Tags: space-rangers-hd

I know that th trading skill increases the % of item's worth you can get in credits, but is there any other way to get more for a piece of equipment?

Comment: In SR2 repaired equipment sells for slightly higher than unrepaired equipment. Not sure though if the cost of repair is larger or smaller than the increase in sell value.

Comment: @MarkRipley just tried this: a damaged drone (~50% damage) in store of a medical station for 48010, after purchase its full price is revealed to be 54300, and it sells for 38408 damaged. Repair cost 6290, and after repair the sell price is 43440 (which is ~90.04811% of the price I bought it at). So it seems like you lose ~10% by buying damaged equipment (at least on 50% damage), repairing and selling it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing trading skill is main way for a better price. But also you can increase a base price of items by upgrading them with certain types of micro-modules.

Third level:

- Platinos. Cost +20%. All equipment.
- Gogaal. Cost +25%. Gaalian only.

Second level:

- Stoplay. Cost +50%. Not for weapons or hulls.
- Impalegun. Cost +25%. For scanners only.
- Paragon. Cost +20%. Peleng grippers only.
- Maform. Cost +60%. Maloq weapons only.
- Jumpgator 3.11. Cost +40%. For engines only.
- Extremer. Cost +60%. Maloq hulls only.

First level:

- Likebaanite. Cost +150%. Gaalian only.
- Broing. Cost +40%. Peleng hulls and protection generators only.

I recommend you to use only Likebaanite and Platinos for selling items because this two micro-modules have no other bonuses.

Comment: I believe it's Iikebaanite. The name is a reference to [Ikebana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ikebana). There's even a text quest called "Master of Iikebaana".

Comment: @z- Cent decrease cost by 75%

Comment: doh, you are right, my bad.  I could've swore there was one that boosts cost by 10%, maybe I'm just remembering wrong

Comment: btw what lange of space rangers HD do you play, the spelling of some of those micromodules are totally different in my english steam version.

Comment: The names should be pronounced similarly, even if the joke is lost on translation. No reason why the devs would use confusing translations.

Comment: @z- I have a russian version but when answered question I looked at GamesFaq.com for english names